# ValueError: could not convert string to float:threshold

Tags: python, threshold

I am having problem with the below command,

```
python signal_arduino_relax.py -t threshold
Setting threshold to threshold
```

While doing this, I got the below mentioned error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "signal_arduino_relax.py", line 122, in <module>
    threshold = float(sys.argv[2])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: threshold
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: try putting an actual threshold value as argument of `-t`: `-t 1.0`

Comment: How about you make `sys.argv[2]` an actual number?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it found the correct documentation...

> `threshold` is a float between 0 and 1 defining the level of relaxtion needed to move the car

Don't verbatim copy the command. Give an actual number, as per the instructions

Comment: Thank you. Jean-François and cricket_007.